# Синтаксис подключения mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Искал информацию по работе с базами данных mysql в php. На одних страницах используется следующий прием

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("адрес_сервера", "имя_пользователя", "пароль");
mysqli_select_db($dbname);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");
```

В других ресурсах используется другой синтаксис

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT * FROM `table`" );
```

Какой синтаксис лучше всего использовать?

Comment: [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php) или [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) c примерами. В том что вы скинули разницы практически нет, единственное это в первом случае база указывается отдельной функцией mysqli_select_db, а во второй передаётся как параметр в mysqli_connect; и апострофы у базы даных во втором случае, что не является обязательным

Comment: давайте еще обсудим, почему в первом примере переменную назвали `$conn` а во втором `$link`

Comment: Ни тот ни другой.